# Quantum State Function $\psi$

Tags: quantum-mechanics

If I write in QM at an instant, that the quantum state that describes the particle completely at an instant $\psi(x)=\cos(6\pi x)$. Does that mean $|\psi(x)|^2dx$ after normalisation gives me the probability that particle will be positioned between $x$ and $dx$ ? What if instead of position it was a function for state of momentum/energy, could I apply born's rule for getting wave function for position ?

Comment: Since this is tagged homework, I'll ask you to take one more step:  normalize the wavefunction, instead of saying "after normalization".

Comment: @garyp done :) .

Comment: @lota You apply a Fourier transform to get the position wave function out of the momentum one, not the Born rule.

Comment: The function is still not normalized.

Comment: Just to note: you do not "write" a wave function, you write the Schrödinger equation and solve it. The solution is the wave function. A function is not a wave function unless it is a solution of the Schrödinger equation for some physical system.

Comment: I still think $\cos(6 \pi x)$ is just an example in the question, though a bad one, since this function is not square-integrable.

Comment: @Wildcat it could be a wavefunction for infinite potential well, $x\in[-\frac14,\frac14]$, for example. There it'd be square integrable.

Comment: @Ruslan, true. I meant that $\cos(6 \pi x)$ is not square-integrable on the whole real line, so it can't be the wave function for a particle not confined to some region of space a priori.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $|\psi(x)|^2 \mathrm{d}x$ gives you the probability to find the particle between $x$ and $x + \mathrm{d}x$. The probability that $x$ will be in the interval $[a, b]$ is then
$$
    P_{a\le x\le b} (t) = \int\limits_a^b d x\,|\psi(x)|^2 \, .
$$
Normalization of $\psi(x)$ to one is required since the probabilities of all possible outcomes should add up to one (the particle is certainly somewhere)
$$
    \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty |\psi(x)|^2 \mathrm{d}x = 1 \, .
$$

If you work with momentum wave function $\psi(p)$, then $|\psi(p)|^2 \mathrm{d}p$ gives you the probability that momentum of the particle is between $p$ and $p + \mathrm{d}p$.

The momentum wave function is related to the position one by a Fourier transform
$$
    \psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \psi(p) e^{\mathrm{i} p x / \hbar} \mathrm{d}p \, , 
$$
while the position wave function is related to the momentum one by an inverse Fourier transform
$$
    \psi(p)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \psi(x) e^{-\mathrm{i} p x  / \hbar} \mathrm{d}x \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question slightly.Please see.

Comment: The range is $[0,1]$ is more than desirable or conventional, it is the first axiom of probability.

Comment: @Iota What is the meaning of a probability outside of the range [0,1]?

Comment: @innisfree, I meant that a wave function is normalized to one to conform to the ("standard") probability theory, in which 1 indicates certainty. But in principle you are not required to adopt this standard. Yes, it is desirable to do so, but it is not required. You can work with probabilities in the range from 0 to 100 (thinking in terms of %), then you normalize your wave function to 10. Math would be a little different, physics will be the same.

Comment: Help me out here.  I've always thought of complex exponentials and delta functions as (non physical) mathematical objects that allow you to get to physical predictions.  The original wave function is not normalizable, and doesn't represent a physical system, so the original question about probability doesn't make sense to me.  E.g., what is the expectation value of the position of the particle represented by that function?

Comment: The wave function is postulated to be square-integrable (normalizable). If a function is not square-integrable, then it can not be a wave function. Nothing to discuss in this case.

Comment: @Wildcat that % symbol looks like and basically means divide by 100. Percentages are normalized to 1. You can't pick any other normalization for a probability. That is literally the first axiom of probability. If you do, you are no longer talking about a probability.

Comment: @garyp a dirac delta function could be a good probability density function. probability *density* can be greater than 1. But any probability cannot.

Comment: @innisfree, yes, that is true. I was wrong.

Comment: @Wildcat no worries, vote reversed!

Comment: Normalization in fact could indeed be not necessary. One could e.g. be interested in ratio of probabilities between two points in spacetime, then the normalization coefficients would just cancel out.